# Nginx - HTTP Post to local file result in 504 Gateway Time-out

Tags: php, http, nginx, http-post

I'm using PHP to test script functionalities. These scripts are supposed to receive HTTP Post request with parameters. I'm trying to send HTTP Post request to these scripts but I'm receiving `504 Gateway Time-out`. I tried to send requests to Internet addresses and everything works fine. Why am I receiving this error when sending HTTP Post requests to local files?

I'm using Nginx 1.10.3 and PHP 7.2.10 in Windows.

Comment: Posting to 127.0.0.1/localhost or back out to the domain? Routing might pick it up and it never resolves, try localhost or an internal ip, also setup the hosts file so your server knows to use localhost for your domain.

Comment: @LawrenceCherone It's pointing to a URL already set up in hosts file. Anyway, it's getting the same behaviour when pointing to `http://127.0.0.1`. Ideas?